# NSDateFormatter show midnight as 24 instead of 00

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

in my application I use `NSDate` and `NSDateformater` to show the hour in the following format : `HH:mm`. When I pass a timestamp that represents midnight for example: `1603843200000`
I expect to get the hour as 00:00, instead I get 24:00. How can I get the hour as 00:00?

Here's the code I use to format the timestamp:

```
NSNumber* timeStamp = currentConsumption.timestamp; // 1603843200000
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([timeStamp longLongValue]/1000)];
NSDateFormatter* df = [NSDateFormatter new];
df.dateFormat = self->graphDateFormat; // @"k:mm"
if(self->graphType == day){
      [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
}
return  [df stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Is the value of `df.dateFormat` `HH:mm` or `k:mm`?

Comment: @Willeke, it was `k:mm`, once I changed it to `HH:mm` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I set the format to be `k:mm` instead `HH:mm`.